# How to run Android Emulator using command line in Macbook Pro M1?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In reference to https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

I list my emulator

```
>emulator -list-avds                                                  
Pixel_3a_API_33_arm64-v8a
```

Then when I try to run it using

```
 emulator @Pixel_3a_API_33_arm64-v8a
```

It complaints

```
Could not launch '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64'
: No such file or directory
```

The problem is, I'm on MacBook Pro M1 machine, where

- I have `sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64`
- But not `sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64`

How can I configure it to search the emulator in `darwin-aarch64` instead of `darwin-x86_64`?

Comment: please take a look at this post
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509202/5857508](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509202/5857508)